# How to center the error message in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

## This is my program from html.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="appScripts.js"></script>
    <title> Log In Page </title>


    <body>

        <div style="text-align:center">
                <img src="lighthouseLogo.png" /><br><br>
                <form>
                    <input type = "text" name="Username" required value="Username" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Username'"
                    onfocus="if(this.value=='Username')this.value=''"><br>

                    <input type = "text" name="Password" required value="Password" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Password'"
                    onfocus="if(this.value=='Password')this.value=''"><br><br>

                    <input type="checkbox"><label class="check" for="checkbox">Remember my login information</label><br><br>


                    <input type="submit" name="Login"value="login"  onclick="checkUserName(this.form.Username.value, this.form.Password.value); return false;">
                </form>
                <div id="msg">  </div>
                <br><br>
                <!-- <div id="help"> </div> -->
                <a href="help.html">Need Help?</a><br>

        </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

*I tried but always the error message is coming on the left side. please help me to get the error message on the center of the page*

## This is my program from javascript

```
function checkUserName (username, password)
{
        if ((username == "susy") && (password == "abc"))
        {   
            window.open('target.html');
        }
        else
        {           
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML= "<i>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</i>";

        }   

}
```

### The error message is coming on the left side but i want on the center. How to do that?

Comment: the code works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to center the content of the `#msg` div:

```
#msg {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same css to center whole div.

```
<style>
   #msg{
   width:400px;
   margin-right:auto;
   margin-left:auto;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#msg{
   width:400px;
   margin:auto;
 }
```

and put position fixed/absolute according to your need